# Why is the compiler using the frame pointer and link register?

Tags: assembly, fortran, gfortran, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to understand how GNU interprets several things so my first example is very simple: declaration of an integer and printing it. If no optimization is invoked, the assembly code reads:

> ```
>     .arch armv8-a
>     .file   "ex1.c"
>     .text
>     .section        .rodata
>     .align  3 .LC0:
>     .string "%i\n"
>     .text
>     .align  2
>     .global main
>     .type   main, %function main: .LFB0:
>     .cfi_startproc
>     stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
>     .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
>     .cfi_offset 29, -32
>     .cfi_offset 30, -24
>     mov     x29, sp
>     str     w0, [sp, 28]
>     mov     w0, 328
>     str     w0, [sp, 28]
>     ldr     w1, [sp, 28]
>     adrp    x0, .LC0
>     add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
>     bl      printf
>     nop
>     ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 32
>     .cfi_restore 30
>     .cfi_restore 29
>     .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
>     ret
>     .cfi_endproc .LFE0:
>     .size   main, .-main
>     .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0"
>     .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
> ```

If the compilation is optimized (-O3), the assembly code is more condensed:

> ```
>     .arch armv8-a
>     .file   "ex1.c"
>     .text
>     .section        .rodata.str1.8,"aMS",@progbits,1
>     .align  3 .LC0:
>     .string "%i\n"
>     .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
>     .align  2
>     .p2align 3,,7
>     .global main
>     .type   main, %function main: .LFB23:
>     .cfi_startproc
>     adrp    x1, .LC0
>     mov     w2, 328
>     add     x1, x1, :lo12:.LC0
>     mov     w0, 1
>     b       __printf_chk
>     .cfi_endproc .LFE23:
>     .size   main, .-main
>     .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0"
>     .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
> ```

Most stuff is relatively straightforward except for the p2align 3,,7 that I'm still figuring out after reading its description at sourceware. However, my main question is something else. Why is the unoptimized version using the frame pointer and link register along with CFA? What is it trying to accomplish? One could wonder why I care, go with the optimized version. The reason is that the optimized version of the Fortran code reverts back to being similar to the unoptimized C version with the use of both frame pointer and link register.
The Fortran code is simply:

```
  program integer_printing

  integer (kind=4) a
  a=328
  write (*,*) a
  end
```

and the optimized assembly code reads

```
        .arch armv8-a
        .file   "exa1F.f90"
        .text
        .section        .rodata.str1.8,"aMS",@progbits,1
        .align  3
.LC0:
        .string "exa1F.f90"
        .text
        .align  2
        .p2align 3,,7
        .type   MAIN__, %function
MAIN__:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        sub     sp, sp, #576
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 576
        adrp    x0, .LC1
        adrp    x1, .LC0
        add     x1, x1, :lo12:.LC0
        mov     w3, 328
        mov     w2, 5
        stp     x29, x30, [sp]
        .cfi_offset 29, -576
        .cfi_offset 30, -568
        mov     x29, sp
        ldr     d0, [x0, #:lo12:.LC1]
        str     x19, [sp, 16]
        .cfi_offset 19, -560
        add     x19, sp, 48
        mov     x0, x19
        str     w3, [sp, 44]
        str     d0, [sp, 48]
        str     x1, [sp, 56]
        str     w2, [sp, 64]
        bl      _gfortran_st_write
        add     x1, sp, 44
        mov     w2, 4
        mov     x0, x19
        bl      _gfortran_transfer_integer_write
        mov     x0, x19
        bl      _gfortran_st_write_done
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp]
        ldr     x19, [sp, 16]
        add     sp, sp, 576
        .cfi_restore 29
        .cfi_restore 30
        .cfi_restore 19
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   MAIN__, .-MAIN__
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .align  2
        .p2align 3,,7
        .global main
        .type   main, %function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 29, -16
        .cfi_offset 30, -8
        mov     x29, sp
        bl      _gfortran_set_args
        adrp    x1, .LANCHOR0
        add     x1, x1, :lo12:.LANCHOR0
        mov     w0, 7
        bl      _gfortran_set_options
        bl      MAIN__
        mov     w0, 0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
        .cfi_restore 30
        .cfi_restore 29
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section        .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
        .align  3
.LC1:
        .word   128
        .word   6
        .section        .rodata
        .align  3
        .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0
        .type   options.1.2778, %object
        .size   options.1.2778, 28
options.1.2778:
        .word   2116
        .word   4095
        .word   0
        .word   1
        .word   1
        .word   0
        .word   31
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Frame pointer is used in unoptimized code to aid in debugging. The optimized version also used a jump to `printf` (tail call elimination). Frame pointer may also be used if you have dynamic stack allocation.

Comment: OK, that answers most of my question. I still don't fully understand why the optimized Fortran version uses the frame pointer (maybe because 'classical' Fortran doesn't use pointers) as the code is definitely not using allocatable variables. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  Instead of asking about irrelevant C code, post your Fortran code and the assembly code it generates and ask why its using a frame pointer with optimization turned on.

Comment: I edited the post to include the Fortran and assembly codes. The assembly code from the unoptimized C compilation is still of interest because the GNU compiler is using the frame pointer as the optimized Fortran compilation (this is one of the points that I'm trying to figure out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason `-O3` doesn't turn on the -`fomit-frame-pointer` option when compiling with GCC for ARM64 targets (including GNU Fortran). You'll need to [enable this option explicitly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MTexWs) for the compiler to optimize away the use of the frame pointer in non-leaf functions:

```
MAIN__:
        adrp    x0, .LC1
        sub     sp, sp, #560
        adrp    x1, .LC0
        add     x1, x1, :lo12:.LC0
        ldr     d0, [x0, #:lo12:.LC1]
        mov     w3, 328
        mov     w2, 5
        add     x0, sp, 32
        str     x30, [sp]
        str     w3, [sp, 28]
        str     d0, [sp, 32]
        str     x1, [sp, 40]
        str     w2, [sp, 48]
        bl      _gfortran_st_write
        add     x1, sp, 28
        mov     w2, 4
        add     x0, sp, 32
        bl      _gfortran_transfer_integer_write
        add     x0, sp, 32
        bl      _gfortran_st_write_done
        ldr     x30, [sp]
        add     sp, sp, 560
        ret
```

Your C example code gets optimized into a leaf function, one that doesn't call other functions, when the compiler changes the tail call to printf (`bl printf`) to a jump (`b __printf_chk`).  That's why the frame pointer is eliminated without using `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Note that the link register can never be optimized away, at least not in any function that can ever return to its caller, as it needs to preserve the value in this register as it contains the address to return to.  In your optimized C example the compiler doesn't need to save or restore the link register (X30).  It simply leaves it unchanged so `__printf_chk` returns directly to the caller of your example C function.  In your other examples, the value stored in the link register is destroyed by the function calls these functions make (by the BL instruction specifically), so needs to be saved and restored.

Finally, the frame pointer has nothing to do with C pointers.  It's used by compilers to access a function's local variables, and also forms a linked list of stack frames that can be used by debuggers to create backtraces and inspect the local variables of calling functions. However on most architectures it's only needed to access local variables if the function makes variable sized stack allocations (eg. for [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)).  On these architectures the stack pointer can be used instead to access local variables when the size of the local variables is fixed, however this comes at the expense of making debugging harder so this is treated as an optimization.

Comment: Thanks. This is great feedback.